# Frontend issue with a js code: the images show good on chrome, edge, but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I have a site, created with a template, that works just fine on Chrome, Edge, Safari, etc... but in firefox it crashes. It's a thing with a JS code that animates the images in the home page. You can see what I'm talking about in [www.andarescolombia.com](http://www.andarescolombia.com)

If you go to that site in chrome you'll see the images on the home page working fine, but on firefox they seem to get collapsed to the top of the container:

## On Chrome:

[image]

## On Firefox:

[image]

So the images collaps in firefox, but the other JS plugins are working just fine. I already tryed to contact the seller, but they just have a lousy customer support service.

Please help!!

Comment: Fix the script errors that are thrown on your page

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your answer, the only error is on main.js:
$(window).load(function($){

 // Trigger window scroll event when page loaded
 // -------------------------------------------------------
 jQuery(window).trigger('scroll');

})

Answer (score 0):

just avoid using $. it should prevent your error from occuring in firefox.
On the other hand why do you want to trigger the scroll event on window.load ? Oo
just wrap the magic you're using inside a function and call it on load and on scroll. saves you a lot of headaches.